# Reuse the code without submitting the form twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

This is all about to implement a **Delete Account** feature in my site.

If user requested to delete his account(It takes 3 days to delete the complete data) and try to login within this 3 days.
We need to ask a confirmation if you are logged in account will be enabled

For that I am using the below code

```
 $('#loginform').on('submit',function(e) {
   var t = $(this);

   $.post('/login.php', t.serialize(), function(data) {
     if(data.error.length) {
       $('.login_result', t).html(data.result).slideDown();

     } else if(data.result == 'waiting_for_deletion') {
       jconfirm('Account will be enabled if you login',
          function(is_confirmed) {
            if(is_confirmed) {                            
               $('input:hidden[name="loginform"]').val('confirm_reactivation');
               ('#loginform').submit();
             }
          } ,
          'Yes', 'Cancel');
         } else {
            location.href = '/accounts';
         }
  }, 'json')
});
```

If user entered correct details (email & password) will ask a confirmation, if he confirmed I am resubmiting the form with a new input field value

I just want to know how Can I reuse my PHP code without submitting the form twice?

or Can I use one more ajax call inside first ajax (I think not possible).

**Also it should not affect normal login**

// EDITED

Here is my PHP code

**login.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['loginform'])) {

    $email = trim(mb_strtolower($_POST['email']));
    $password = $_POST['upw'];


    if (empty($email)) {
        $error['#email'] = 'Wrong mail';
    }
    validate('password', $password, $error['#password']);

    // check for correct password now
    if(!$error) {

        $data = query_execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".sqlescape($email)."' LIMIT 1");

        if(!$data) {
            $error['#email'] = 'Account not exists';

        } elseif(!$data['active'] && !(int)$data['validated']) {
            $error['error'] = 'Account not validated';

        } elseif(!$data['password'] || !check_password($password, $data['password'], $data['userid'])) {
            $error['#password'] = 'Wrong password';

        // ----------------------------------------------
        // OK, ALL FINE! USER COULD LOGIN
        // ----------------------------------------------
        } else {

           $confirmation = $_POST['loginform'] == 'confirm_reactivation' ? true : false;

            $Delete_Accounts = query_execute("SELECT * FROM deleteacoount WHERE email='".sqlescape($email)."' LIMIT 1");

            // Waiting for Deletion accounts
            if ($Delete_Accounts[$data['userid']] == 2 && !$confirmation) {
                $result = 'waiting_for_deletion';
            } else {
                if($confirmation) {
                    query_execute("DELETE FROM deleteacoount WHERE email='".sqlescape($email)."'");
                }

         DB_query("UPDATE users SET last_login=NOW(),
                               last_ip='".$_POST['ip']."'                                  
                           WHERE userid=".$userid."",'#');

                $result = 'OK';
            }
        }
        // ----------------------------------------------
    }

    if($error) {

        $result = '<div class="alert alert-block alert-error mb5"><h4>'.$error.'</div>';

    }

    jsonReturn($result, $error);
}
```

Comment: @Armin: Please check my edited code

Comment: Just my 2 cents - this is how I would design this use case (1.) User submits `Account Delete` form. This adds a flag to their account (`account_delete_requested`) and also the date/time. (2.) Have a CRON job run daily/hourly that checks for these flags/date/time and deletes anyone older than 3 days. (3.) Completely separately, each time a user logs in, check for the `account_delete_requested` flag/date/time and reactivate if within 3 days.

Comment: @waterloomatt: You are right , I am doing in the same way. But I just want to ask a confirmation when user tries to log in

Comment: Can you make PHP return JSON that represents 3 different states: 1. Error (Invalid username/pwd), 2. OK (Valid username/pwd && account **does not** have the `account_delete_requested` flag set, 3. ACTIVATE (Valid username/pwd && account **does** have the `account_delete_requested` flag set). Then, the JS would look at that status and either: show error msg, redirect to a landing page, show confirmation dialogue; if confirmation dialogue = Y, redirect to landing since you know username/pwd is OK. This way, you don't need to submit the form again; the confirmation dialogue will drive itself.

Comment: @waterloomatt: You are brilliant , and that is good way . But I also want to update `last login` and delete the user from `deletedaccounts` table, if the result is ok. Also it should not affect normal login

Comment: OK - so 2 scenarios here: (1.) "Normal Account" and username/pwd is correct - update `last_login`, return JSON `OK`. (2.) If the account is waiting for deletion, just return JSON `ACTIVATE` from PHP. Then, in JS, if confirmation dialogue = Y, fire an AJAX request to reactivate the account which will update `last_login` and delete the record, and finally, redirect to the landing page. Something like `$.post('/activate.php')...; location.href...;` **1 major issue though. PHP will set session flags during login. You probably don't want to do that if the user chooses "N" on the dialogue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I am using one extra ajax call and reusing existing code to create another PHP file to solve this problem without submitting a form twice.

**Script**

```
$(".password").on('focus', function () {
        var email=$('input[name="email"]').val();
        confirm_reactivation(email);
});

function confirm_reactivation(email)
{

var api="email="+ email;
         $.ajax({
        method : 'POST',
        url : confirm_reactivation.php,
        data : api
      }).done(function(data){
        var out = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
        if(out.message == 'success'){
             $('input:hidden[name="loginform"]').val('confirm_reactivation');
        }else{
               $('input:hidden[name="loginform"]').val('');
        }
      });
}

$('#loginform').on('submit',function(e) {

  var check_value=$('input:hidden[name="loginform"]').val();
if(check_value !='' || check_value == null)
{
var t = $(this);

   $.post('/login.php', t.serialize(), function(data) {
     if(data.error.length) {
       $('.login_result', t).html(data.result).slideDown();

     } else {
            location.href = '/accounts';
         }
  }, 'json')
}
else{
       jconfirm('Account will be enabled if you login',
          function(is_confirmed) {
            if(is_confirmed) {                            

$('input:hidden[name="loginform"]').val('confirm_reactivation');
               //('#loginform').submit();
var t = $(this);


   $.post('/login.php', t.serialize(), function(data) {
     if(data.error.length) {
       $('.login_result', t).html(data.result).slideDown();

     } else {
            location.href = '/accounts';
         }
  }, 'json')
             }
          } ,
          'Yes', 'Cancel');

}


});
```

and here is your new PHP file, I have reused your code and added few things.

**//confirm_reactivation.php**

```
<?php

 $email = trim(mb_strtolower($_POST['email']));

  $Delete_Accounts = query_execute("SELECT * FROM deleteacoount WHERE email='".sqlescape($email)."' LIMIT 1");

            // Waiting for Deletion accounts
            if ($Delete_Accounts[$data['userid']] == 2) {
                $message = array("message" =>'success',"status" =>200);
 echo json_encode($message);exit;
            }
            else{
             $message = array("message" =>'failed',"status" =>200);
 echo json_encode($message);exit;
            }



?>
```

That's it. Thank you!

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki No, if you have read my code properly you can come to know this. His question was same time he doesn't want to submit a form twice, in my program if you are a normal user you can submit a form only once or if you are a deleted user and coming back again at this time also you can submit a form only once. Thank you!

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I found my logic error and fixed, check now. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You need to write function for ajax, and after modify object - submit it again

```
function submitForm(form) {
    $.post('/ajax.php', form.serialize(), function (data) {
        if (data.error.length) {
            $('.login_result', form).html(data.result).slideDown();

        } else if (data.result === 'waiting_for_deletion') {

            jconfirm('Account will be enabled if you login',
                function (is_confirmed) {
                    if (is_confirmed) {
                        form.find('input:hidden[name="loginform"]').val('confirm_reactivation');
                        submitForm(form);
                        return;
                    }
                },
                'Yes', 'Cancel');
        } else {
            location.href = '/me';
        }
    });
}

$('#loginform').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    submitForm($(this));
});
```

Comment: This way we split the function. But submits the form twice , Right?

Comment: @Sree first time we call `request = submitForm(_this);` and catch response by `request.done`, but second time we just call `submitForm(_this)` after modify it

Comment: How can we catch the response as we get different responses each time?

Comment: submitForm(form); same function is called twice(form submitting twice). I don't want that. Please read my Question

Comment: First call, if account is active - redirect to "/me", but if account waiting_for_deletion - you need to show confirm popup. After confirm - send request with `confirm_reactivation`. Or other option - you can use sockets.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know why you don't want to submit the form twice.

In anyway, there are 2 goals must be achieved:

1. The user must know his/her account is `waiting_for_deletion`
   and confirm to login.
2. The server must know that user confirmed.

There is a solution for you: Load all `waiting_for_deletion` emails when you load login page (you can hash it for security reason). After user entered his/her email, you can compare the entered email and `waiting_for_deletion` list. If the email is existed in the list, show the confirm popup.

This solution is not good about performance (you must load the email list anytime render login page), security (you load a list of email and check in client side, ever if you hashed emails on the list, it is also a weak point). But, it can achieve your goal.